# Best way to store the user role in angular application

Tags: angular

In my angular app authentication functionality work with single sing on option, after the successful login cookie will be saved for my app, with cookie value call the api to get the user details along with user roles etc and storing in local storage.

Based on the role in dashboard page there is a acl operation need to be validated, currently stored the user details and roles in the local storage. since local storage can be modified through console is there any best way to keep the detail?

is there any best way to keep the data results in service and access in the components?

Comment: 1. You don't need to store the roles in local storage: you can just keep them in memory. 2. Whatever you do, there is no such thing as client-side security. The user can do whatever it wants with his browser, whether of not you use local storage. You can use roles at client-side to hide or disable actions that the user shouldn't have access to, but in the end, it's the **server** responsibility to prevent users from doing stuff they're not allowed to do.

Comment: The role is a very small information that you can reload on refresh without big deal. You can keep it in your store if you want to handle display differences depending on the user role. Of course user can always find a way to do the backend calls for functions he is not supposed to do, and you need to prevent that in your backend.

Comment: @JBNizet: memory meant : service variable?

Comment: Yes, for example.

Comment: @JBNizet If I use a service to keep the roles stored locally and make a browser refresh once having logged in, then I will get an error because probably I will have a condition similar to `<div *ngIf="role === ''admin">show something</div>` and then the role variable will be undefined and the html that I want to hide will not be hidden anymore. What should I do then? Redirect the user to login page?

Comment: I'm working through this right now and the issue with localstorage is it's far too easy to elevate the role making all the UI checks meaningless. At least if you hide it, they'll have to leverage more sophisticated techniques that will at least slow an attacker down. Still not sufficient for security but it's likely going to be more difficult digging through the web packed sources to override those checks.